# Interior is always open verification

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Another from Rudin. Just wanting feedback on conciseness, correctness, and style.

> Prove $E^\mathrm{o}$ is always open.

Let $p \in E^\mathrm{o}$. Find $r >0$ such that $N_r(p) \subset E$.

We know neighborhoods are open.

So, $\forall q \in N_r(p), \exists r' > 0$ such that $N_{r'}(q) \subset N_r(p) \subset E$. Thus $q$ is an interior point of $E$ and belongs to $E^\mathrm{o}$.

Thus $N_r(p) \subset E^\mathrm{o}$.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are claiming $q$ is an interior point of $E$ or of $E^{\circ}$.  Also, *do* we know that neighborhoods are open?

Comment: $N_{r'}(q) \subset  N_r(p) \subset E$ shows that $q$ is interior to $E$ doesn't it? And yes, from Rudin 2.19 >every neighborhood is an open set.

Comment: Ah, yes,, we do know neighborhoods are open by 2.19.  So $q$ is an interior point of $E$ so $q \in E^{\circ}$ so so $N_r(p) \subset E^{\circ}$ so $E^{\circ}$ is open.  Yes, this is good.

Comment: Yes, your proof is good but to make your thought process crystal clear state $q$ is interior point of E and so $q \in E^{\circ}$.  Just to make it absolutely clear to anyone reading it... even an absolute dope like me.

Comment: Absolutely. I appreciate the feedback. I'm trying to develop more succinct proof writing. So everything helps.

Comment: Well, you do have to take critique with a grain of salt.  What is clear to someone will be vague to another will be mind-numbingly repetitive and redundant to a third.  Your proof was good but giving it the 30 second glance over I wasn't  immediately sure that you were claiming all $q$ where in $E^\circ$ but slowing down to 45 seconds it *was* clear.  So... I'm a bit worried I was being to harsh.  You proof *is* correct and anything *not* clear (in a 30 second glaze) you know how to justify.  So that's the important part.  It's good.